# Could it be possible to create a pentane steam engine?

Tags: heat-engine

I'm questioning if there's a way to make use of the principle of steam engines again.

The idea of a  steam engine is a little primitive and outdated maybe, but the principle isn't that at all
if you ask me.
In the 19th century, they used water for steam engines and I assume this fluid was chosen because of the wide availability and low costs.
The cons of using water is that you have to burn fuel like coal for heat because of the relatively high boiling point of water.
Back in those days, those fuels were still widely available, but obviously those times have changed.

The thing is, if you use a fluid with a much lower boiling point you'd have to add only a little bit of energy onto it to make it boil.
So to obtain the best efficiency, you'd take a fluid which has a boiling point near the environment temperature.
For example, pentane boils at 309K / 36C. (I don't know which substance is more suitable)

I don't know how much energy you gain when this substance boils, but if you have a closed circuit for the fluid and a radiator, you could in theory build an engine which runs indefinitely.
Because the energy you gain from the boiling substance is big enough to generate the little heat which is needed to make it boil.
Maybe this is a stupid question, and i suppose this has been considerated a long time ago.
But i'm just curious about it. And then again, the simple or weird ideas are the ones who actually work. :p
Thanks for any response.

Comment: The basic principle of a steam engine (convert heat to mechanical motion through boiling water) is used in many types of power plants. Even a nuclear power plant in the end does nothing but drive a modern version of the steam engine with the heat of the nuclear reaction. However, a low-heat steam engine would be very inefficient, no matter how it is realized, due to the fundamental laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: Your question about different working fluids is a good question. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_fluid#Applications_and_examples) also mentions others than water, but does not mention what the advantages are. However, your final paragraph suggests that pentane would allow you to make a perpetuum mobile, but that would definitely not be the case.

Comment: Thnks, but not a perpetuum, because you use the heat of the environment. But pentane has a boiling point near the environmental temperature.

Comment: Putting less energy into boiling means getting less energy out as work.  And the boiling point is perhaps not as important as the enthalpy of the phase transition to indicate the energy available for work.

Comment: @JonCuster "Putting less enrgy into boiling means less energy out as work" Why is that? Could you refer me to, or give an explanation as to why this is true?

Comment: Bart, because of the First Law of Thermodynamics (which is just Energy Conservation wearing a hat and fake mustache---he's such a kidder).

Comment: @Bart - where does the energy come from for a steam engine to perform work? Think in that for a bit...

Comment: @JonCuster The energy is generated by burning fuel or another heat source but my idea was that it costs less energy since you have to add less heat to make the substance boil. Because the environment makes it almost boil already

Comment: @Bart - sure, but then there is less energy to get back out when it condenses.  You need to think more about how the cycle works.

Comment: I almost for sure knew i was wrong but i was just curious how and why. I'm interested in the phenomenom so i asked this question. you guys have done a good explanation as to why and how so thanks for that. the law of thermodynamics is quite complicated so i didn't got any wiser from that. Some help and explanation does come in handy then.

Answer (score 1):

Pentane is used as a medium in low-enthalpy heat engines.

See, for example, David Banks. Introduction to thermogeology,

The efficiency of such engines is quite low, as it has an upper limit of the Carnot efficiency at the operating temperatures. Nevertheless, if you have a temperature difference between two regions that you can exploit without too much expense, it can be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I have given the exact same question some thought recently. To make progress I worked through what would happen with methanol instead of pentane. What I did was work through what would happen after condensing, and the work that could be done by the resulting vacuum, ignoring vapour pressure. I worked out you should get about 5% efficiency.

Remember this is thermal efficiency from what can be a near limitless supply of low grade heat. Condensing colder and using higher pressure may mean butane can be used. Turbines also need a makeover, would like to see them on "air" bearings. Any oil would end up contaminating things. With computer simulations now should be able to 3D print something good 1st time.

As a retired person I can add that my belief is that Carnot efficiency is an oversimplification. Basically if you want to get anything working you will have to fund it yourself, because no business would sensibly fund work against an established theory.

Beyond the boiling point there is the critical point or something, where the pressure is such that gasification is instant from liquid with no added energy when the pressure is reduced. Using butane may be better for this. Physicists in refrigeration -heat pump people- should know exactly what to do to get things working and keep them safe.

The development can mirror the development of steam engines in the industrial revolution. To begin with they used pistons and air pressure and the efficiency was about 4%. Then they used high pressure steam and turbines and they got closer to 50%.

Comment: I guess you get the necromancer badge right away for this answer, because i posted it 8 years ago :p (earned by reviving an old threat) Anyway, in the meantime I got into engineering, got my bachelor, and now I understand that this idea wouldn't work. Water is still used because it's by far the cheapest, you can waste it after you're done. The energy you get by expansion is approx, proportionally to the amount you put in by heating it. So pentane wouldn't cost much energy, but wouldn't give much either. You could use a heat pump to increase efficiency, but only in some cases that's profitable.

Comment: 4% of what is essentially free is still a good deal. Depends on the build cost and how it compares to other renewables where you are, including maintenance and environmental impact. Things have changed from 180 years ago; now coal is bad. The Royal Navy ruled the waves for over 50 years thanks in part to high pressure steam. There are now budgets for trying all different types of renewables. If people say the theoretical maximum is 0.5%, might not be a starter, even if the theory is a dated simplification made for good reasons.

Comment: Saw a video with medium (village) scale hydro power from Nepal. There the bearings needed a monthly inspection. If you can get your copper/ magnets to "fly" or "float" on a moving stream of gas, there are no bearings getting worn out the whole time.

Comment: Congrats for your degree! Low boiling point fluids are sometimes used to take advantage of low grade heat, the search term is "organic Rankine cycle". Example: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/organic-rankine-cycle

Answer (score 0):

this topic has been in my mind for a long time. The mindset is always to use a specific part of the energy to convert for e.g electricity.
Think about your homes in colder regions. In Germany we have good grade fireplaces with 80% efficiency. But 20% goes to the chimney. The heat (tested many times with Thermo cams is around 150-200 °Celsius. so working backwards the airvolumes which the fireplaces usually need for combustion and hence convection drafts in the chimney, this 20-30 % losses matches to the energy given off by the firewoord. Lets call a 10kw fire (e.g 2.5KG wood) burns for an hour. 80% is given to your room or eventually partially to the water jacket), the rest 2 KW escapes to the chimney (as this is your actor to draw in new air for combustion/oxygen replenish.
Now you could take a little fan and divert the offgas into a thermal heat exchanger with heat resistant fluid (thermal oil, engine oil or whatever). Next step you could use PENTANE (boiling point 50°C and heat up to 150-200°C). Now use the pressure and expansion to drive a little turbine (screw/scroll/piston) or whatever suits for the convenient size and take it out as electricity. Upon partial condensation, use an economizer to cool down to create the heat sink required to liquify the PENTANE back to under 50°. The rest energy use it to heat water for your central heating or shower/bath water. In case this is already higher in temperature in a buffer central tank, then use it for a radiator to heat your rooms. then possibly coming out with 25-30°C rest heat. Again use this rest energy in another tank + heat exchanger to preheat the incoming council water (in winter this is in between 6-10°C). Like this the efficiency is a tremendous upgrade. And not even high tech. Not sure why nobody is using it. Possibly have to create this myself in the garage. Only scary part is the Pentane maybe escaping some seals in the turbines and hence the risk of fire eventually. But all this could be engineered out. Greets from Germany, Bernd

Comment: Hello Bernd and welcome to Physics SE. I strongly suggest you format your question a little bit to be easier to read. This will help, both to attract the attention of the people here as well as to help them understand your problem better.